# How to query for just values that timestamp is more than 24hs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So , I have made this code to check for values inside my orders collection that are older than 24 hs, this is dued I want to send a remember notification to my user that they need to accept the order.

```
exports.rememberToFinishOrder = functions.pubsub.schedule('3 * * * *').onRun(async (context) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    const tsToMillis = db.Timestamp.now().toMillis()
    const compareDate = new Date(tsToMillis - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) //24 hs
    let snap = await db.collection('orders').where("timestamp","<",compareDate).get()
    return snap.forEach(async(doc) => {
        const userId = doc.data().uid
        let userSnap = await db.collection('user').doc(userId).get()
        userSnap.forEach((doc) => {
            const deviceToken = doc.data().deviceToken
            const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: "Did you got your order?",
                body: "If so, dont forget to accept the order in your orders tab."
            }
        }
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken,payload)
        })
});

});
```

so here I'm trying to get just orders which accepted time (timestamp) is greater than 24 hs, but I think that `db.Timestamp.now().toMillis()` is not working, my log says that

```
 ReferenceError: db is not defined
     at exports.rememberToFinishOrder.functions.pubsub.schedule.timeZone.onRun
 (/srv/index.js:131:16)
     at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:127:23)
     at /worker/worker.js:825:24
     at <anonymous>
     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

But I suspect that the problem is on

`db.Timestamp.now().toMillis()`

I'm doing it right ?

Comment: What does `admin.firestore().Timestamp` and `admin.firestore.Timestamp` returns?

Comment: You're chasing at the wrong problem here, the error `ReferenceError: db is not defined` states that the variable `db` is `undefined`. Therefore, the object returned from calling `admin.firestore()` is the one responsible for the error. You must  check as to why `admin.firestore()` is not returning the correct data you're expecting

Comment: It returns two different things, first one Any and the other one the Timestamp , I will check if that is the problem, thanks @palaѕн

Comment: Cool. If you are getting Timestamp, you can simply convert it to a JavaScript Date object using [`toDate()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate)